# Linq more condition on the same row

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I have following query to get some rows

```
Where(x =>  (x.Year >= 2012 && x.Month >= 12) && (x.Year <= 2013 && x.Month < 2))
```

and this should return me `2012.12` and `2013.1` but of course it won't return any rows because there are none for `month >=12` and `month <2`, so my question is how to check month only for rows where year is euqal to sth?

ex. check `month >=12` only for rows where `year >= 2012 and check month <2` only for rows where `year <= 2013`.

I should mention that my sql table has no dateTime fields only

```
[Year] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month] [int] NOT NULL,
[Value] [float] NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ex,

```
Where(x => x.Year*12+x.Month >= 2012*12+12  && x.Year*12+x.Month < 2013*12+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make a range query from December of 2012 through February of 2013. In this case you could use a condition below:

```
Where(x => ((x.Year > 2012 || (x.Year == 2012 && x.Month == 12)) // >= 12 makes no sense
         && (x.Year < 2013 || (x.Year == 2013 && x.Month < 2))
)
```

The trick is to specify different conditions for the month based on `x.Year >` vs `x.Year ==`, rather than using `x.Year >=`.

Of course a simpler approach would use `x` as a whole date, like this:

```
Where(x => (x >= date.make(2012,12,01) && x <= date.make(2013, 02, 01)))
```

**EDIT :**

> check `month >=12` only for rows where year `>= 2012` and check `month <2` only for rows where `year <= 2013`

The above translates into this LINQ expression:

```
Where(x => ((x.Year < 2012 || (x.Year >= 2012 && x.Month == 12))
         && (x.Year > 2013 || (x.Year <= 2013 && x.Month < 2))
)
```

Comment: yee if that fields where of type DateTime, please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] and this should return me 2012.12 and 2013.1

makes me think what you want to express is:

```
Where(x =>  (x.Year == 2012 && x.Month >= 12) || (x.Year == 2013 && x.Month < 2))
```